# unity canvas ui press

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to when pressed mouse button call Left function. I sought in google but don't found.

```
    Button OnClickLeftButton = LeftButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    Button OnClickRightButton = RightButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    Button OnClickJumpButton = JumpButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    Move_Player = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<MovePlayer>();
    OnClickLeftButton.onClick.AddListener(Left);
    OnClickRightButton.onClick.AddListener(Right);
    OnClickJumpButton.onClick.AddListener(Jump);
}
void Left () 
{
    Move_Player.MoveLeft();
}
void Right () 
{
    Move_Player.MoveRight();
}
void Jump () 
{
    Move_Player.MoveJump();
}
}
```

Comment: Try replacing .AddListener(Left) with -> .AddListener(delegate{Left();}); and tell me something ^^

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If you add some logging, does anything happen?

Comment: No I haven't error.I want to function left or right call when mouse button pressed.